# How to delete jar files and other libraries that i don't need in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, refactoring, jar

Somewhere in some of my projects or maybe in eclipse, there are some jar files that i dont use them any more, and now the console displays this warnings every time i build even if it has nothing to do with the current problem:

```
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class 'org.richfaces.taglib.CalendarTagHandler' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class '[ns582:handler-class: null]' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class 'org.richfaces.taglib.ColumnTagHandler' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class 'org.richfaces.taglib.ColumnsHandler' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class '[ns621:handler-class: null]' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class 'org.richfaces.taglib.RowKeyConverterComponentHandler' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class 'org.richfaces.taglib.DataFilterSliderTagHandler' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class 'org.richfaces.taglib.RowKeyConverterComponentHandler' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class 'org.richfaces.taglib.RowKeyConverterComponentHandler' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class 'org.richfaces.taglib.RowKeyConverterComponentHandler' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class 'org.richfaces.taglib.RowKeyConverterComponentHandler' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class 'org.richfaces.taglib.DataScrollerTagHandler' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class '[ns676:handler-class: null]' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class 'org.richfaces.taglib.DragSupportHandler' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class 'org.richfaces.taglib.DropDownMenuTagHandler' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class '[ns691:handler-class: null]' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class 'org.richfaces.taglib.DropSupportHandler' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class 'org.richfaces.taglib.FileUploadTagHandler' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class '[ns721:handler-class: null]' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class 'org.richfaces.taglib.GraphValidatorHandler' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class '[ns814:handler-class: null]' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class 'org.richfaces.taglib.PageTagHandler' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class 'org.richfaces.taglib.Paint2DTagHandler' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class 'org.richfaces.taglib.PanelMenuGroupTagHandler' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class 'org.ajax4jsf.webapp.taglib.AjaxComponentHandler' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class 'org.richfaces.taglib.ScrollableDataTableTagHandler' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class '[ns886:handler-class: null]' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class 'org.richfaces.taglib.SimpleTogglePanelTagHandler' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class '[ns900:handler-class: null]' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class 'org.richfaces.taglib.RowKeyConverterComponentHandler' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class 'org.richfaces.taglib.SuggestionBoxTagHandler' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class 'org.richfaces.taglib.TabPanelTagHandler' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class 'org.richfaces.taglib.HtmlToolTipTagHandler' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class 'org.richfaces.taglib.TreeTagHandler' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class 'org.richfaces.taglib.TreeNodeTagHandler' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class 'org.ajax4jsf.taglib.html.facelets.ActionParamHandler' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class '[ns1004:handler-class: null]' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class 'org.ajax4jsf.webapp.taglib.AjaxComponentHandler' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class 'org.ajax4jsf.webapp.taglib.AjaxComponentHandler' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class '[ns1019:handler-class: null]' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class 'org.ajax4jsf.webapp.taglib.AjaxComponentHandler' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class 'org.ajax4jsf.taglib.html.facelets.IncludeHandler' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class '[ns1044:handler-class: null]' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class 'org.ajax4jsf.taglib.html.facelets.MediaOutputHandler' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class 'org.ajax4jsf.webapp.taglib.AjaxComponentHandler' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class 'org.ajax4jsf.taglib.html.facelets.AjaxPushHandler' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
WARNING: JSF1029:  Application is versioned at 2.0 (either explicitly by the version of /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml or the lack of a /WEB-INF/faces-confg.xml), however class 'org.ajax4jsf.taglib.html.facelets.AjaxSupportHandler' depends on a legacy facelet class.  The facelet artifact represented by this class will not be registered.
```

How can i get rid of this libraries and avoid that this message. This is also making eclipse build my projects slower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved. To erase all the libraries that i dont need i just need to go to eclipses properties and find build path. When i just erased them from the lib folder they weren't remove from the build path.